The listings package and side-by-side code listings
I'm using the listings package liberally in an article. However, I
want to show some code listings side-by-side and for those i use the
subfigure package:
\begin{figure*}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
        \begin{lstlisting}
            ...
        \end{listing}
    \end{subfigure}            
    \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
        \begin{lstlisting}
            ...
        \end{listing}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure*}

The problem here is that this is a figure, consequently the caption
will be prefixed with "Figure X:" and LaTeX will use the figure
environment's float counter rather than the listing environment's
counter.
How do I fix this? I want LaTeX to treat the above code as essentially
one (floating) listing.

start by showing a small but complete example that can be used to test the issue and solutions.

Since lstlisting supports float and caption options, it must create its own float type.  The problem with a "one environment does everyting" approach is separating the float from the display.  IIRC, they used to have separate listing and lstlisting environments.

Right, I'm using listings's builtin floats for simple listings. But the environment is insufficient for side-by-side code listings.

I tried using the built in lstlisting float type (\@float{lstlisting}[#1]) but could not get it to work with subcaptions.  Specifically, every lstlisting increments the lstlisting counter, reseting the subcounter.  So instead I created a separate float type for listing.
Note that this causes \lstlistoflistings to stop working.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lst, listname={List of Listings}]{listing}
\DeclareCaptionSubType{listing}

\begin{document}
\listoflistings

\begin{listing}[h]
\caption{Test}
\begin{sublisting}{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}
  \begin{lstlisting}
  left listing
  \end{lstlisting}
  \caption{}
\end{sublisting}\hfill
\begin{sublisting}{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}
  \begin{lstlisting}
  right listing
  \end{lstlisting}
  \caption{}
\end{sublisting}
\end{listing}

\end{document}


Of course, if you don't want subcaptions, the original solution works fine.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{listing}[1][htp]{\@float{lstlisting}[#1]}{\end@float}
\newenvironment{listing*}[1][tp]{\@dblfloat{lstlisting}[#1]}{\end@dblfloat}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings

\begin{listing}
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}
  \begin{lstlisting}[caption=Test A]
  left listing
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}
  \begin{lstlisting}[caption=Test B]
  right listing
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{listing}

\end{document}

